# Why instance initialization block is not throwing compile time error for duplicate entry?

Tags: java

from my understanding ,like static blocks are used to initialize static variables, usually instance initialization block is used to initialize instance variables.
if tats the case why in my code its not throwing compile time error for ***"duplicate field k"***

```
    package inheritance;

public class Testanon {
    Anony a;
    int k=10;
     {
        Anony a = new Anony(){};
        int k=9;//duplicate field k
    }

    public Testanon() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Anony a = new Anony(){};
    Testanon test = new Testanon();
System.out.println(test.k);
System.out.println(a.name);
    }
void met() {
    Anony a = new Anony(){};
}
}
```

output is : 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a` and `k` variables declared inside your instance initializer block are local variables, not instance variables. They simply hide the instance variables of the same name.

If you wrote

```
Anony a;
int k;
{
    a = new Anony(){};
    k=9;
}
```

you'd be initializing instance variables in the instance initializer block.

There's a reason they are called "instance **initializer** blocks" and not "instance **declaration** blocks". You can use them to initialize already declared instance variables, not to declare new instance variables.

Another way to look at it is to copy the code of the instance initializer block to the constructor, since that's equivalent to what happens when an instance is created:

```
Anony a;
int k;
public Testanon() {
    Anony a = new Anony(){};
    int k = 9;
    // other code that appears in the constructor body
}
```

Again, you can see `a` and `k` are local variables, that hide the instance variables of the same name.

Comment: my question was why its allowing *declarations* if its just *initializer* ? i guess its not hiding either,  if i initialize `int k=10` it takes the actual initialized value(10) , not the value initialized by **'IIB'**

Comment: @amarnathharish You are allowed to declare local variables inside any `{}` block. It doesn't matter if it's a static initializer block, instance initializer block, constructor, method or an inner block within some method.

Comment: @amarnathharish that's not true. If you write `int k=9;` inside an instance initializer block, the instance variable `k` will remain unchanged (it will contain 0 by default).

Comment: i meant initiaizing directly **outside** IIB

Comment: @amarnathharish the fact the `int k=9;` inside the IIB doesn't affect the instance variable `k` means the local `k` of the IIB hides the instance variable `k`.

Comment: " the local k of the IIB hides the instance variable k"  if this is true why its NOT printing `9` which is initialized inside IIB. check, the question is edited for clear understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172972/discussion-between-amarnath-harish-and-eran).

Comment: @amarnathharish because a local variable exists only until the execution leaves the block in which it is declared. Once the instance is created, the local variables `a` and `k` are no longer accessible. The instance variables `a` and `k` are no longer hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It is called `instance initializer block` and  not `instance declaration block`. hence anything declare there will be local and used only within given block.

Try printing value of k and you will get `0` as result Because it create a local variable for the given codeblock. 
Again in the block try using `this.k = 9;`and you will have updated value.

Comment: it works but how `this` can be used since we havent finished constructor call?

Comment: instance initializer block is executed before the constructor call and after the super().